# Join two tables and return rows with N values in common

Tags: sql, join

I have two databases with identical schema that I merged and now I want to return the records that are possible matches.

That is, return three records in the updated database that might look like:

```
id        foo       bar       baz       meow      mix
36        123       234                           567
962       123                 345       456       567
962                           345
```

I want to be able to search for records that have any n column values in common (here n=2 obviously). In the example, records 1 and 2 have identical 'foo' and 'mix' values and records 2 and 3 have identical 'id' and 'bad' values.

I know it should be an INNER JOIN but my problem is that I want it to be able to return any records that have any n column values in common so I don't know what to join them on.

```
SELECT * FROM table t1 INNER JOIN table t2 ON ...
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Addendum:

@Gordon Linoff

Ok, that worked! I generalized it for any table and any number of columns and excluded identical matches with:

```
"SELECT t1.*, t2.* FROM {0} t1 JOIN {0} t2 ON {1} WHERE ({2}) BETWEEN 2 AND {3}".format(table, ' or '.join(['t1.{0}=t2.{0}'.format(c) for c in columns]), '+'.join(['(CASE WHEN t1.{0}=t2.{0} THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)'.format(c) for c in columns]),len(columns)-1)
```

Thanks!

UPDATE: The table I am reforming this on has ~10k records and this is so slow! Is there a faster way to do this?

Comment: It may be a good idea to build function taking 5 arguments and returning number of pairs. Then run this function agains every row by putting function into WHERE clause.

Comment: @huhu78 What would that look like?

Comment: function in pseudocode: int f(arg1,arg2,arg3,arg4,arg5) { compare everything, count pairs, return pairs }; then in query: SELECT id FROM tab1 WHERE f(col1,col2,col3,col4,col5) >= n; Use of function may be more readable, more reusable, give opportunity to write function with few steps

Comment: @JoeFlip . . . If you have a question about performance, you should ask another question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a self-join and `order by`:

```
select t1.*, t2.*,
       ((case when t1.id = t2.id then 1 else 0 end) +
        (case when t1.foo = t2.foo then 1 else 0 end) +
        (case when t1.bar = t2.bar then 1 else 0 end) +
        . . .
       ) as NumMatches        
from table t1 join
     table t2
     on t1.id = t2.id or
        t1.foo = t2.foo or
        t1.bar = t2.bar or
        . . .
order by NumMatches desc;
```

If you want exactly two or more matches, then that depends on the database.  In MySQL you can say `having NumMatches >= 2`.  In other databases, you either have to repeat the `case` statement in the `where` clause or use a subquery.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt you are going to find any shortcuts...you're going to need to spell out all the matches you want, ie:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE foo=bar or foo=baz or foo=meow or foo=mix, ...
```

Comment: I don't want to match foo and bar, etc. You mean 'WHERE t1.foo=t2.foo OR t1.bar = t2.bar' I assume. But that would be absurd since I'd have to write out every possible permutation to match multiple columns, i.e. "WHERE (t1.foo=t2.foo AND t1.bar=t2.bar) OR (t1.foo=t2.foo AND t1.baz=t2.baz)" etc.